# Why ARToolKit Android show object in wrong position and perspective on Moto X 2nd Gen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, artoolkit

I runned the project "ARSimpleNativeCarsProj" from ARToolKit Android SDK examples following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAWyUQ1xaNs.

Ok, I dont changed the code and it works, but the problem is when I run this application sample on Motorola Moto X (2nd Generation), it looks funny, it is looking wrong position and perspective, but in another cell phone it works normally.

I shared on my google drive, images of the problem, .apk and markers (if you wanna try on your Moto X 2nd), here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9yAAVb6fwJ8OU9rdmMxQnN4Z2s&usp=sharing

(Sorry if it isn't better way, I do that cause I can't to post image here)

So, I tried anothers projects on web, only using ARToolKit I have this problem.

Is happening this problem only on my Moto X2 or is it a problem with ARToolKit?

Any idea how can I fix this?

**[Edited] [Solved]**

As suggested by [Gizmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5843642/gizmo) and [shalafi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539171/shalafi) I calibrated and tried differents resolutions, now it works for me.

Comment: Have you seen/done these steps: http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=2_Configuration:config_camera_calibration

Comment: Yes, it was just the calibration. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you run the camera calibration for you phone. See tutorial here:
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_camera_calibration

This will upload the calibration and fetch it the next time you run an ARToolKit app.

I recommend this because your example image looks like a calibration might help.

You can download the calibration app here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.artoolworks.ar.utils.calib_camera

Let me know if it worked for you.

Best

Comment: Ok, I will try this and I post here the result.

Comment: It was just the calibration, now it works, thanks a lot. Will work it in others Moto X 2nd Gen or their phones have to make calibration too?

Comment: @RaphaelBruno, could you please tag the answer as solution as it might help others which may not read the comments :).

Comment: I can't use tag on title, at field tag does not have [solved] tag. "Title contains a [tag] prefix; please use the tag field to enter tags instead."

Comment: I meant the little green check mark beside the answer. To mark the answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

Running the calibration is a great suggestion, you should start by doing that.

As a side suggestion try changing the camera resolution and see if it works better with other resolutions. I have found myself that some cameras have weird FOV parameters in certain resolutions.